# How to create a function in mathematica to solve for 'x' for later use?

Tags: matrix

I would like to create the quadratic formula in mathematica, multiplied with the identity matrix 5. How to store it for later use?

I would like to be able to input a,b,c when I later call the function and then have it solve for 'x'.

What I have so far is:

qF[a_,b_c_]:=ax^2*IdentityMatrix[5]+bx*IdentityMatrix[5]+c=0

I would like to be able to call upon it later and have it solve for 'x':

qf[1,2,3] = .... solved for 'x'

Thank you

Comment: `bx` is different from `b x`; mind the space for multiplying variables!

Comment: @J.M. How might this be written out given my example?

Comment: You want something like `a x^2` in there.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you. As far as multiplying with IdentityMatrix[5] is this the appropriate way in mathematica?

Comment: Simply put: use `.` (`Dot[]`) if you're multiplying a matrix with a vector or another matrix, and `*` (`Times[]`) if you're multiplying a matrix with a scalar.

Comment: @J.M. For right now just scalars like time, speed or random numbers. So for this that would equate to: qF[a_,b_,c_]:=a x^2(Times[IdentityMatrix[5]])^2+b x(Times[IdentityMatrix[5]])+c=0