# How does one make a function in Mathematica to later call and solve it?

Tags: function-construction

Such as if I wanted to make a quadratic function, save it, and then later plug in any values of a,b,c in order to solve for `x`.

This was what I was thinking it would be:

```
fQ[a_,b_,c_]:=a x^2+b x+c ==0
```

Then I want to be able to call it and solve it with arbitrary values

```
Solve[fQ[1,2,3],x]
```

I then get this:

Set::write: Tag Plus in 3+2 x+x^2 is Protected.

Solve::eqf: 0 is not a well-formed equation.

Thank you

Comment: @Kuba Meant to have originally wrote that in the question. Has been corrected.

Comment: Works fine for me. If in doubt restart your kernel.

Comment: Duplicate:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169311/how-to-create-a-function-in-mathematica-to-solve-for-x-for-later-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mySol[a_, b_, c_] := Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]

mySol[1, 2, 3]
```

$\left\{\left\{x\to -1-i \sqrt{2}\right\},\left\{x\to -1+i \sqrt{2}\right\}\right\}$

Your problem was that you tried to include `x`, which is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What if with the x^2 and the x I wanted to multiply it by the identity matix 5? I thought it might be: aFunc[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Solve[a x^2*(Times[IdentityMatrix[5]]) + 
    b x*(Times[IdentityMatrix[5]]) + c == 0, x]

Comment: However, the output is giving me Out[]={} when I type in aFunc[1,2,3]

Comment: If you try to mix matrices (`IdentityMatrix[]`) and scalars (`c`) you don't have a valid equation.  Moreover, this extension is not part of the question as stated and it is very bad etiquette indeed to ask a question, get a full answer, not accept or up-vote it, and then say... oh... but what I *really* wanted to ask is...

Comment: Apologies for doing that. It was a two part question. I should have merged into one.

Comment: Gosh... so not even a simple upvote??

Comment: Nothing personal there. Just very new to this format.